# default param in js reduce is ignored

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been playing with default variables in JavaScript but I can't get this example to work on anything (node 10.16.3, firefox 69, chrome 76)

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.reduce( (acc = 5, el) => acc + el)  // -> 6
```

It fails silently and yes I know I can accomplish the same thing by passing in an initial value after the callback. I just want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 77.  How is it failing silently?  It should throw an error to your console if it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acc = 5` will only use `5` as the default if the value would otherwise be `undefined`.

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you don't supply an initial argument in the form of `arr.reduce(callback, initial)`, then the *first element* of the array is used and the iteration starts from the second element of the array:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.reduce( (acc = 5, el) => {
  console.log(acc, el);
  return acc + el;
})  // -> 6
```

So, the only way to have `acc` be `undefined` is if you *explicitly* set it as such via the initial parameter, or if the first element is `undefined`:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

let initialiseWithUndefined = [1, 2, 3].reduce( (acc = 5, el) => acc + el, undefined)  // -> 11
console.log(initialiseWithUndefined);

let firstItemIsUndefined = [undefined, 2, 3].reduce( (acc = 5, el) => acc + el)  // -> 10
console.log(firstItemIsUndefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
`initialValue` *Optional*

> A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no `initialValue` is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped. Calling `reduce()` on an empty array without an `initialValue` will throw a TypeError.

So `[1, 2, 3]` iterated 2 times, with values `[2, 3]` and accumulator `[1]`